# Add sound player to django admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have model with `FileField`, which contains audio file:

```
class Word(models.Model):
    theme = models.ManyToManyField(Theme, related_name='words')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    sound = models.FileField(upload_to='sounds/', blank=True)
```

I need show audio player on admin panel for this model.

For example, for `ImageField` I did this:

1. `from django.utils.html import mark_safe` and add property to model code

```
@property
def icon_preview(self):
    if self.icon:
        return mark_safe(f'<img src="{self.icon.url}" width="100" height="100" />')
    return ""
```

2. in `admin.py` add code:

```
list_display = ('id', 'name', 'icon', 'icon_preview')
readonly_fields = ('icon_preview',)

    def icon_preview(self, item):
        return item.icon_preview

    icon_preview.short_description = 'icon preview'
    icon_preview.allow_tags = True
```

And I need to do something similar for the sound

Comment: Okay. What are you having trouble with? Sounds like you know how to render an image, and you probably know about the `<audio>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be working:

1. Add to model `Word` this property:

```
@property
def sound_display(self):
   if self.sound:
       return mark_safe(f'<audio controls name="media"><source src="{self.sound.url}" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>')
   return ""
```

2. In `admin.py` add this construction:

```
   list_display = ('id', 'name', 'transcription', 'translation', 'example', 'sound_display')
   readonly_fields = ('sound_display',)
   list_display_links = ('id', 'name')

   def sound_display(self, item):
       return item.sound_display

   sound_display.short_description = 'sound'
   sound_display.allow_tags = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could link to the audio file, similar to what you did for the image, and let the browser play the file when the user clicks the link.

For example, using [format_html](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html):

```py
from django.utils.html import format_html

@admin.display(description='Sound', ordering='sound')
def sound_display(obj):
    link = 'not available'
    if obj.sound:
        link = format_html('<a href="{}">sound</a>', obj.sound.url)
    return link
```

and then use it like this in your `list_display`:

```py
list_display = (..., sound_display)
```

You could also use the HTML [`<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) tag, [as suggested by @AKX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72613647/add-sound-player-to-django-admin-panel#comment128268178_72613647).

Comment: It works, the link is displayed, but my task is to display the audio player on the entity edit page. The ImageField field displays a picture, not a link